# The [us-federal-government] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

We have a tag [us-federal-government](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-federal-government) with no description.  Most of the questions with that tag seem that they should be tagged [united-states](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) instead, as that is the preferred tag for questions about the federal legal system of the United States.

Should [us-federal-government](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-federal-government) be made a synonym of [united-states](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states), or is it important to distinguish them?

Comment: Agreed, this is an unnecessary step of detail that fits under an existing tag,.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that [us-federal-government](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-federal-government) should actually be 'burninated' - its trying to do something that would be better done with two separate tags: [united-states](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) and [government](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government).

It is not a synonym for [united-states](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) because there are many questions that fall that tag that have nothing to do with [government](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government).

On further reflection, I can see a need for a family of [government](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government) tags - [national-government](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/national-government), [state-government](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/state-government) and [local-government](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/local-government).

Comment: Note that we don't currently have a [tag:government] tag.

Comment: This could work well

Answer (score 1):

There are questions that are specific to U.S. federal law and federal government, and it makes sense to distinguish these from questions about law in the U.S., which could apply to states or multiple levels of government.

As of this post there were 22 questions tagged [federal-law](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/federal-law), and almost twice as many tagged [us-federal-government](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/us-federal-government).  As a start, I just merged and synonymized the former tag with the latter.

Comment: "Federal law" could equally refer to Australia, Russia, Germany or Brazil. It should not be a synonym of "USA federal government" regardless of what a previous ignorant user with bias to the latter decided to presume for the former.